# Оценка кода своей реализации TreeSet

Tags: java, коллекции

Дали задание создать свою реализацию `TreeSet`, в котором должны быть методы `add(E e)` и `List<E> get()`.

Корректно ли мой код иллюстрирует работу `TreeSet`? Если некорректно, то в чем?

Если хотя бы отчасти корректно, то как мне протестировать, что я создал именно дерево, ведь мой метод `get` по условию задачи возвращает `List`?

Реализуемый интерфейс:

```
public interface Tree<E> extends Iterable<E> {
    boolean add(E e);
    List<E> get();
    int size();
}
```

Сама реализация:

```
public class SimpleTreeSet<E> implements Tree<E> {
    private Leaf<E> root;
    private List<E> list;
    private int size = 0;

    public SimpleTreeSet() {
        list = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (size == 0) {
            return initRootLeaf(e);
        }
        Leaf<E> newNode = new Leaf<>(e);
        Leaf<E> lastNode = findLastLeaf(root, newNode);
        if (lastNode == null) {
            return false;
        }
        // храню элементы для итератора и get
        list.add(newNode.element);
        if (lastNode.compareTo(newNode) > 0) {
            lastNode.right = newNode;
            size++;
            return true;
        } else {
            lastNode.left = newNode;
            size++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // ищу последний лист дерева
    private Leaf<E> findLastLeaf(
            final Leaf<E> oldLeaf,
            final Leaf<E> newLeaf
    ) {
        Leaf<E> lastLeaf = oldLeaf;
        int compare = oldLeaf.compareTo(newLeaf);
        if (compare > 0 && oldLeaf.right != null) {
            lastLeaf = findLastLeaf(oldLeaf.right, newLeaf);
            return lastLeaf;
        }
        if (compare < 0 && oldLeaf.left != null) {
            lastLeaf = findLastLeaf(oldLeaf.left, newLeaf);
            return lastLeaf;
        }
        if (compare == 0)
            return null;
        return lastLeaf;
    }

    private boolean initRootLeaf(final E e) {
        root = new Leaf<>(e);
        list.add(e);
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> get() {
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }

    private class Leaf<E> implements Comparable<E> {
        private Leaf<E> right;
        private Leaf<E> left;
        private E element;

        private Leaf(E element) {
            this.element = element;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof SimpleTreeSet.Leaf) {
                Leaf<E> node = (Leaf<E>) obj;
                return this.hashCode() - node.hashCode();
            }
            throw new ClassCastException();
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 31;
            hash = hash * 17 + element.hashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну было бы логично что бы get возвращал отсортированный список. И кстати не сам список, а его копию(!) иначе кто угодно может поломать структуру дерева. После этого сам список можно вообще убрать из дерева (он не нужен).

Comment: 1. Было бы здорово увидеть в вопросе код интерфейса `Tree`, ибо без него пример не воспроизвести. 2. Хранить `List` в данном случае некорректно, ибо метод `get` возвращает неотсортированный список - смысл во всём дереве резко пропадает. Список стоит собирать с нуля прямо в `get`. Это заодно защитит от поломки дерева извне. 3. В `if (lastNode.compareTo(newNode) > 0) - else` строки `size++;` и `return true;` есть в обеих ветках - значит, их можно вынести за `if-else`.

Comment: 4. Почему бы в методе `hashCode()` у `Leaf` не возвращать просто `element.hashCode()`? Прибавление константы (`31 * 17`) никак делу не поможет.

Comment: 5. Не вижу смысла в проверке `if (obj instanceof SimpleTreeSet.Leaf)`. Во-первых, в противном случае всё равно выбрасывается `ClassCastException`, а во-вторых, это `private` класс, так что можно быть более-менее уверенным в том, что `obj` является `Leaf<E>`. Да что уж там: можно вообще отказаться от `implements Comparable<E>` и сделать метод `compareTo(Leaf<E> leaf)`. Это, возможно, спорное утверждение, но зачем делать маленький вспомогательный внутренний класс "универсальным"?

Comment: @Regent 1. Добавил код интерфейса в самый конец. 2. Если собирать список с нуля то мне нужно будет как-то по этому дереву хитро проходить? или можно его собрать и и тут-же отсортировать? 3. Да спасибо не заметил. 4. Я прибавляю эти константы потому что все говорят что это правильный способ переопределения hashCode(). 5. Спасибо!

Comment: 2. Да, нужно будет "как-то хитро проходить". Думаю, создание дерева и его обход - это то, ради чего задание и задумывалось. 4. А эти "все" как-то аргументируют своё мнение, и действительно ли они имели в виду простую прибавку `527`?

Comment: @Regent 4. я так понял это в контексте проблемы коллизий наверно вы правы тут это вообще не нужно тут массива то нет какие нафиг коллизии...

Comment: Коллизии возможны (если два неравных `element` возвращают один и тот же хэш код), однако прибавка константы ко всем хэш кодам никоим образом не помогает избавиться от коллизий. Это, кстати, ещё одна проблема: у вас, судя по коду, не может храниться несколько элементов с одинаковым хэш кодом, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: @Regent  да с коллизиями я тут не представляю как быть... тут как c HashSet не получится массива то нет. Не знаете как тут можно с ними поступить?

Comment: Чтобы в одно узле можно было хранить несколько элементов, вместо `private E element;` нужно хранить, например, список элементов: `private List<E> elements;`. Кстати, а в задании ничего не говорится про сбалансированность хранимого дерева? Ибо если дерево должно быть сбалансированным, то метод `add` значительно усложнится. По-хорошему, дерево должно быть сбалансированным, но это всё же учебное (или тестовое ли) задание, так что, возможно, это и не нужно. Как знать - может, и объекты с одинаковым хэш кодом не предполагаются. Это надо спрашивать у того, кто давал задание.

Comment: @Regent Про List понял спасибо. Вообще до сбалансированного я должен его усовершенствовать в следующем задании, а в чем разница между сбалансированным и нет?

Comment: Чтобы сделать дерево сбалансированным, вам всё равно придётся самому про него читать (и, возможно, немало, ибо балансировка - дело непростое в понимании) в интернете, но суть в том, что дерево сбалансировано, если длина всех веток (путей от корня до листьев; под листьями тут подразумеваются узлы, у которых нет подузлов) различается максимум на 1.В Википедии есть альтернативная формулировка, имеющая тот же смысл: "для каждой вершины высота её двух поддеревьев различается не более чем на 1".